# How to remove "column border" in selectonemenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a SelectOneMenu component with 2-column select items, like this example: http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

How can I remove those borders between the first and the second column?

I'm getting this:
[image]

But I would like to get something like this: 
[image]

I tried with CSS property `border-style` on column, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: It is an HTML table. Looking into the generated HTML code would help.

Comment: This CSS class comes into mind - `.ui-selectonemenu-table td {...}`. These style properties are applied there `border-width: 1px; border style: solid; border-color: inherit; padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I managed to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a tip from @Tiny, I managed to remove borders with the following CSS code:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-table td, .ui-selectonemenu-table tr{
   border-style: hidden !important;
}
```